# PERL script AKAITOOLS accessing USB Iomega Zip drive on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: perl

I am running a Perl script trying to access an Iomega ZIP drive on Ubuntu Linux, and it is returning the following error:-

```
new: /dev/mo: Bad file descriptor
```

This is on either running either of the following commands:-

```
akailist
```

or

```
for i in *.a3s; do akaiwrite -d /breaks/ "${i}"; done
```

The script I am running is from AKAITOOLS, to save audio files in AKAI .as3 format to an AKAI formatted Iomega ZIP disk for use in an Iomega ZIP drive connected to an S3000XL sampler.

The AKAITOOLS Perl scripts are available here:-

http://www.lsnl.jp/~ohsaki/software/akaitools/

A description of the process for successfully running this can be read here:-

http://www.mpc-forums.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=178525

These scripts are pretty old (1998) - and I have successfully used them in the past.

I would be grateful for any suggestions/ help to resolve this issue

Answer (score -1):

Create a symbolic link (symlink) from `/dev/mo` to the device file of your zip drive.